# JQuery Getting value undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following JQuery script:

```
var loaded_data = {};
function data_load(callback) {
    $.getJSON('get_data.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (fieldName, fieldValue) {
            loaded_data[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        });
    });
    callback();
}

function add_data() {
    alert(loaded_data["courses"]);
}

data_load(function () {
    add_data();
});
```

The function **data_load()** working properly and loading data. But when I am trying to call **add_data()** function, I am getting **Undefined**  in alert message.
If I am Typing **loaded_data["courses"]** on console on browser, I am getting desired output.

[image: Browser Console]

I don't know **loaded_data["courses"]** is working properly on Browser console but not on script.

Is There anything like **alert()** is executing before loading data from **get_data.php**?

Comment: the misstake is: you call the callback outside the getJSON callback. -> put callback one line up. directly after `$.each`. Explanation: when you call `add_data()` the getJSON is simply not yet finished.

Comment: What happens if you use console.log instead of alert in add_data()?